# OpenShift: can't connect to MySQL db with a cron python script

Tags: python, mysql, cron, openshift, portforwarding

I'm setting up an application on OpenShift. It requires a Python script to run every hour and extract data from an online server into a MySQL database on OpenShift. I've been filling this database for some time now by running the Python script locally on my computer and using the port-forward technique. This works like a charm. Underneath is the port-forwarding info that's displayed while doing this.

```
Service Local               OpenShift
------- -------------- ---- -------------------
httpd   127.0.0.1:8080  =>  127.12.248.131:8080
mysql   127.0.0.1:3306  =>  127.12.248.130:3306
node    127.0.0.1:8081  =>  127.12.248.129:8080

Press CTRL-C to terminate port forwarding
```

And the variables I use in my local script...

```
host='127.0.0.1'
user='user_placeholder'
passwd='password_placeholder'
db='3v3'
port=3306
```

Of course I'd like the script to run automatically on the server of OpenShift so I don't have to do so myself. After a quick search I stumbled upon the cron method. It's possible to just put a python script in a map to make it run every hour. I set up some environment variables to access my database, just like I did in the local script. However, the script can't seem to connect to the MySQL database when I tail it. I've even printed the environment variables out and they're exactly the same as the ones I used to succesfully port-forward.

```
host=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_HOST'] # prints '127.12.248.130'
user=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_USERNAME'] # prints 'user_placeholder'
passwd=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'] # prints 'password_placeholder'
db=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_NAME'] # prints '3v3'
port=int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_PORT']) # prints 3306
```

The error message:

> ```
> File "/var/lib/openshift/57c57f1889f5cfd9bb00006b/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/cron/minutely/test.py",
> ```
>
> line 36, in 
>       db = MySQLdb.connect(host=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_HOST'],
>   user=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_USERNAME'],
>   passwd=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'],
>   db=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_NAME'],
>   port=int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_PORT']))
>
> ```
> File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py",
> ```
>
> line 81, in Connect
>       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ```
> File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py",
> ```
>
> line 187, in **init**
>       super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
>
> ```
> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.12.248.130' (113)")
> ```

I honestly don't know where this could go wrong. I know that it's not much of a lead but if anyone thinks to know what the problem could be, I'd be glad to hear.

Comment: describe on what boxes what works talking to what. This is completely vague. We need to know a lot more detail than the above

Comment: @Drew added some additional info

Comment: Is the database and the script apart of the same Openshift app? You cannot a access a database from another server.

Comment: @fatfantasma The database belongs to a NodeJS app... The other app is a Python one but I thought I read somewhere it was possible.. It would really suck if it turns out it isn't possible, any alternatives?

Comment: I always thought you could not cross apps.

Comment: @fatfantasma what if you want to do something like me? It sounds really delimiting if you can only access the database with one application

Comment: I think you might be able to do it on the paid tiers.  No sure. Othewise can you write your script in nodejs?  Or maybe manually installing python.exe on your nodejs app.  Never done this before.  I'm just thinking outside the box: )

Comment: @fatfantasma It's quite a big script, it would take a lot of time to convert to nodejs :( how exactly would you install python on the nodejs app? Using ssh?

Comment: I have only used python gears on openshift so I don't know if it's even possible.  I would attempt to copy a python executable (and whatever else is needed) into the Openshift data directory via WinSCP or similar.  Then use a bash script to call your python script.  Another thought.  Could your nodejs app provide an api to copy your database to your python app. It's totally inefficient but it would work. Or how about using a cloud based MySQL server so both apps can access the same database?

Comment: @fatfantasma Actually, my nodejs app needs the database and the python script is just filling it. Any recommendations on what platform to use?

Comment: I'm not sure about MySQL cloud.  But I just used mLabs mongodb free tier yesterday.  Google "heroku mysql" or "free MySQL cloud" and you will find something.