# OpenShift: can't connect to MySQLdb with a cron python script

Tags: python, mysql, cron, openshift

I'm setting up an application on OpenShift. It requires a Python script to run every hour and extract data from an online server into a MySQL database on OpenShift. I've been filling this database for some time now by running the Python script locally on my computer and using the port-forward technique. This works like a charm. Underneath is the port-forwarding info that's displayed while doing this.

```
Service Local               OpenShift
------- -------------- ---- -------------------
httpd   127.0.0.1:8080  =>  127.12.248.131:8080
mysql   127.0.0.1:3306  =>  127.12.248.130:3306
node    127.0.0.1:8081  =>  127.12.248.129:8080

Press CTRL-C to terminate port forwarding
```

And the variables I use in my local script...

```
host='127.0.0.1'
user='user_placeholder'
passwd='password_placeholder'
db='3v3'
port=3306
```

Of course I'd like the script to run automatically on the server of OpenShift so I don't have to do so myself. After a quick search I stumbled upon the cron method. It's possible to just put a python script in a map to make it run every hour. I set up some environment variables to access my database, just like I did in the local script. However, the script can't seem to connect to the MySQL database when I tail it. I've even printed the environment variables out and they're exactly the same as the ones I used to succesfully port-forward.

```
host=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_HOST'] # prints '127.12.248.130'
user=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_USERNAME'] # prints 'user_placeholder'
passwd=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'] # prints 'password_placeholder'
db=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_NAME'] # prints '3v3'
port=int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_PORT']) # prints 3306
```

The error message:

```
File "/var/lib/openshift/57c57f1889f5cfd9bb00006b/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/cron/minutely/test.py", line 36, in <module>
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_HOST'], user=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_USERNAME'], passwd=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'], db=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_NAME'], port=int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_EXTMYSQL_DB_PORT']))

File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)

_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.12.248.130' (113)")
```

I honestly don't know where this could go wrong. I know that it's not much of a lead but if anyone thinks to know what the problem could be, I'd be glad to hear.

Comment: Mysql error 113 means no route to host. Confirm your connectivity between source and target first.

Comment: Instead of abandoning a question from the day prior, try to engage the conversation there

Comment: @Drew I tried to make my setup more clear in this question, that's why I posted it again

Comment: That is not how we roll here :p

Comment: @d1ll1nger how could I test this? I'm assuming the python script and the database get hosted on the same server?

Comment: @Drew so I delete the old question or what would you want me to do?

Comment: I edited your other question

Comment: @Drew ok, thanks, so we continue there?

Comment: Yes, I recommend that @d1ll1nger post that `113` over [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681552) and continue the conversation there. Feel free to ping me. And delete this in 10 minutes